# strange behaviour of h2o glrm

Tags: r, h2o

I am using H2O GLRM's to build a binary recommender system (example data files attached). I am using the current version of H2O, 3.10.3.6 in R., following suggestions from [recommender](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-meetups/blob/master/2016_11_16_ODSC_Recommenders_H2O/recommenders-with-h2o.Rmd) and [meetup](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-meetups/blob/master/2016_11_16_ODSC_Recommenders_H2O/recommenders-with-h2o.Rmd).

I generated a train (train.wmiss) from another data set (train.nomiss) allowing for 20% of missing values. All columns in train data sets are binary factors (encoded with N, Y).

I was trying to fit a glrm using following command:

```
#generate a train and a test set
train.h2o.wmiss<-h2o.insertMissingValues(train.h2o, fraction = 0.2) #train has 20% missing value
train.h2o.nomiss<-as.h2o(train) #test has no missing value

 glrm_k <- 3
 glrm_cols <- colnames(train.h2o.nomiss)
 ncols<-h2o.ncol(train.h2o.nomiss)
 #fitting a logistic GLRM
 base_glrm <- h2o.glrm(training_frame = train.h2o.wmiss, cols = glrm_cols, k = glrm_k, 
                       validation_frame = train.h2o.nomiss, seed = 1,
                       loss_by_col=rep("Logistic",ncols),
                       regularization_x = "Quadratic", regularization_y = "Quadratic", gamma_x = 0.1, gamma_y = 0.1, transform = "NONE", impute_original = TRUE, 
                       model_id = "myglrm")`
```

I am noticing that the train and the test set shows the same classification error. Is it right or a potential bug?

Comment: Your variable names makes it looks like you are passing your training set to `validation_frame`.  Did you make a typo and pass your training set accidentally?  That would explain why you get the same classification error.

Comment: Hi Erin, the train.h2o.nomiss (validation) is a copy of the "train" set with NO missing value, whilst the train.h2o.wmiss (train) is the same data set with 20% missing value... Reading various post I have understood that the approach for training / validating GLRM is to provide the same data set but in the train add some missing values.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the h2o.insertMissingValues you are changing the original dataset as well. Creating two separate h2o instances and then changing just one, should solve the problem.

```
train <-- as.h2o(A)
test <-- as.h2o(A)
h2o.insertMissingValues(train, fraction = 0.2, seed=-1)
```